# for each object in json result how to create a object and assign object properties

Tags: python

```
class Device(object):
    data = None

    def __init__(self, properties):
        self.data = json.loads(properties)
        pass
```

This is my device class and I want to assign properties to my object created by Json results using loops in python. my device properties are `'description' 'device_type','facility','id','latitude','longitude','sequence','source','update_date','web_url'`

Comment: Use list comprehension to create objects and keep them in lists. You could make a function to convert the json properties to a list. Then just pass the list as "properties" for each object. If json props are in a list you could do `listDevices = [device(prop) for prop in jsonList]`

Comment: ^ If you want to give the devices unique names instead of referring to them by list index, use a dict instead and map the key to the ID Property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to accomplish this. First would be to use the `setattr` method:

```
other_properties = {'device_type': "usb", 'id', '12345'} # and on and on

d = Device(properties=some_properties)

for k, v in other_properties.items():
    setattr(d, k, v) # this will set d.<key> = value
```

This is relatively simple and easy to read, however some might complain about setting `self` attributes outside of `__init__`.

Next, you can pass in the properties as a `dict` like before and unpack them in `__init__`:

```
class Device:
    def __init__(self, **properties):
        for k, v in properties.items():
            setattr(self, k, v) # again using setattr
```

Or if you already know what that dictionary of items is, you can set your keyword args on `__init__` ahead of time and unpack them that way

```
class Device:
    def __init__(self, id=None, device_type=None, latitude=None): # ad nauseum
        self.id = id
        self.device_type = device_type
        ...

d = Device(**properties) # This syntax will unpack properties into the correct keyword args
```

Another approach could be to call `update` on `Device.__dict__`, though there are definitely valid arguments on why *not* to do this

```
class Device:
    def __init__(self, properties):
        self.__dict__.update(properties)
```

Finally, the question could be raised "do you even *need* a class here?" If you want to just store key-value pairs you could use a `dict` and just use `dict`-style access paradigms:

```
d = {**properties}
d.get('id') # 12345
```

Or if you want class style access, you could use a `namedtuple`:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Device = namedtuple("Device", ['id', 'device_type', ...]) # Your other kwargs go here

d = Device(**properties)
d.id # 12345
```

To create many instances of the classes/namedtuples, you can do that with a list comprehension or for loop

For loop:

```
devices = []
for properties in records: # Where records is a list of json properties
    devices.append(Device(**properties))
```

List comprehension

```
devices = [Device(**properties) for properties in records
```

## Edit: Using json

The code above assumes that `properties` behaves like a `dictionary`, `**` unpacking will take a dictionary and unpack it into the correct keyword arguments on a function definition. If you are passing a `string`, this won't work, which is why you are using the `json` module.

`json.loads` parses a `string` object into a python object type. For example:

```
import json

r = json.loads('["a", "b", "c"]')
# listType ['a', 'b', 'c']
# r is a list object containing the strings 'a', 'b', 'c'
```

It is most commonly used with returning dictionaries from json-formatted strings

```
mystr = '''
{ "id": 12345,
  "device_type": "usb",
  "loc": "abc12345"}'''

my_obj = json.loads(mystr)
# my_obj is a dict now
```

To put this in context with what you have defined in your problem, let's say you have a json_string `property` and you want to load that into a `class` like I have done above. First using your method:

```
class Device:
    def __init__(self, property_string):
        properties = json.loads(property_string)
        for k, v in properties.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)
```

To use the methods I have outlined above, you will just take that `json.loads` call and do it *outside* the class:

```
class Device:
    def __init__(self, id=None, device_type=None, ...): # all of your attrs go there
         self.id = id
         self.device_type = device_type
         ... # more of the same here

properties = json.loads(property_string)
d = Device(**properties)
```

Comment: when using the 3 code its throwing an error type argument after ** must be a mapping not module

Comment: In `Device(**properties)`, the `properties` var is assumed to be of type `dict`. What type are you passing into the class?

Comment: ah is `properties` a `string`?

Comment: I m passing string

Comment: Ok, so if `json.loads(properties)` yields a `dict`, then my edit should work. What is returned by `json.loads(properties)`?

Comment: See my new edit, hopefully it clears up what the `json.loads` function is doing

Comment: Below the vote buttons there is a checkmark that you should be able to click on